# PHP Search query in any order

Tags: php, symfony, search

I have a search that is functional, it's able to search multiple keywords. So for example you have 'You are awesome' in you db, you can find it by searching 'You awesome' but when you search for 'Awesome are you' it will return nothing. So basically you can only search in the same order as in the database if you get what I mean. I hope you guys can help me with this. Thanks in advance!

Controller:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class VoorraadlijstenController extends Controller
{

    /**
     * @Route ("/voorraadlijst", name="voorraadlijst")
     */
    public function voorraadlijstHomepage(Request $request){

        //Variabelen
        $zoek = $request->get('q');
        $search = explode(" ", $request->get('q'));
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $waarde = '';

        foreach ($search as $key) {
            $waarde .= '%'.$key.'%';
        }

        $parameter = [];
        $parameters['query1'] = '%'.$zoek.'%';
        $parameters['query2'] = '%'.$waarde.'%';


        //Ophalen van data uit database.

        if ($search) {
                $voorraad = $em->createQuery('Select a FROM AppBundle:Voorraadlijst a WHERE a.artikelnummer LIKE :query1 OR a.omschrijving LIKE :query2 ORDER BY a.omschrijving ASC')
                ->setParameters($parameters);
            } 
        else {
                $voorraad = $em->createQuery('Select a FROM AppBundle:Voorraadlijst a ORDER BY a.omschrijving ASC');
            }

        //Verwijzing naar overzicht & en variabelen die hij meegeeft
        return $this->render('voorraadlijst.html.twig', [
            'voorraad' => $voorraad->getResult(),
            'q' => $zoek
        ]);
    }

}

?>
```

Twig:

```
{% extends 'layout/default.html.twig' %}

{% block content %}

    {#Style voor de wrapper#}

    <style>

        .wrapper {
        height:     130px;
        min-height: 150px
        margin:     10px;
        padding:    30px;
        }

        table {
          table-layout: fixed;
          zoom: 80%
        }

    {#Style voor de zoekformulier#}

        .zoekformulier{

        padding: 20px;
        margin-top: 20px;
        }


    </style>

     {#Heading#}

    <div class="wrapper" style="background-color:#E9ECEF">
        <div class="container">
            <h3 class="display-4"><center>Voorraadlijst week 29</center></h3>
        </div>
    </div>

    {#Zoekformulier#}

    <div class= "zoekformulier">
        <form>
            <input name="q" value="{{ q }}" placeholder="Artikelnummer of omschrijving" />
            <button type="submit">Zoeken</button>
        </form>
    </div>

    {#Tabellen, tr aanpassen, td laten staan#}

    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                <table class="table table-striped">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="col">Artikelnummer</th>
                        <th>Omschrijving</th>
                        <th>Adviesprijs</th>
                        <th>Nu beschikbaar</th>
                        <th>Eerste LEV Verwacht</th>
                        <th>Beschikbaar na eerste LEV</th>
                        <th>Tweede LEV Verwacht</th>
                        <th>Beschikbaar na tweede LEV</th>
                        <th>Derde LEV Verwacht</th>
                        <th>Beschikbaar na derde LEV</th>
                        <th>Vier de zomer %</th>
                        <th>Vier de zomer €</th>
                        <th>Opmerking</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    {% for artikel in voorraad %}
                    {#Onderstaande wordt opgehaald vanuit je entiteit en die haalt het op uit je database. Niet aanpassen!#}
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="row">{{ artikel.artikelnummer }}</th>
                        <td>{{ artikel.omschrijving }}</td>
                        <td>{{ artikel.adviesprijs }}</td>
                        <td>{{ artikel.nuBeschikbaar }}</td>
                        <td>{{ artikel.eersteLevVerwacht }}</td>
                        <td>{{ artikel.beschikbaarNaEersteLev }}</td>
                        <td>{{ artikel.tweedeLevVerwacht }}</td>
                        <td>{{ artikel.beschikbaarNaTweedeLev }}</td>
                        <td>{{ artikel.derdeLevVerwacht }}</td>
                        <td>{{ artikel.beschikbaarNaDerdeLev }}</td>
                        <td>{{ artikel.kortingProcent }}</td>
                        <td>{{ artikel.kortingEuro }}</td>
                        <td>{{ artikel.opmerking }}</td>
                    </tr>
                    {% endfor %}
                    </tbody>
                </table>              
            </div>
        </div>
        <hr>
    </div>


{% endblock %}
```

I shall look into ElasticSearch and queryBuilder. Question closed.

Comment: you should use one of the search engines like Elasticsearch, SphinxSearch, Solr :)

Comment: @DenisAlimov So there is no way to do this with PHP built-in functions?

Comment: break query string by spaces => "you are awesome" => 3 words "you" "are" "awesome". Then make search by all words like `WHERE text LIKE $word1 OR text LIKE $word2 OR text LIKE $word3`. Not efficient, but it will work in most cases

Comment: @DenisAlimov I did that with the explode explode function and added it to a loop and matched it in the query. But it doenst make me able to search in a different order.

Comment: @MrJ. I think there's no better way than using LIKE, but you can do what you want, but it won't be really efficient. 

1. I suggest you using queryBuilder
2. Your first query is incorrect (no and between checks)
3. Just generate all combinations

Comment: @revengeance Thank you for your reply, I shall look into queryBuilder. This question can be closed then.

Comment: Well, QB won't make a big difference, but it's more readable, understandable imo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite of search engines allow to do it in the less complicated way, there is SQL approach: you could use `RLIKE` operator instead of `LIKE`.

The base query will be looked like `SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE fieldname RLIKE 'you.*awesome'`. Note that `RLIKE` doesn't use any indexes (but in your particular code above `LIKE` also will not use any indexes, because expressions are started with wildcard symbol `%`)